# How to securely limit columns in postgres logical replication?

Tags: postgresql, replication, permissions, security

The [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/202112172107.i5ebyfyrifk7%40alvherre.pgsql) currently have this to say about publications with specified column lists:

> The choice of columns can be based on behavioral or performance reasons. However, do not rely on this feature for security: a malicious subscriber is able to obtain data from columns that are not specifically published. If security is a consideration, protections can be applied at the publisher side.

From [the pgsql-hackers thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/4f832e27-20a4-964a-fafd-edf39e0ae883%40enterprisedb.com) that landed this feature, it sounded like the concern was primarily about the `COPY` command during the initial table sync. There was a brief mention about using column privileges instead.

Is that a workable approach? Which user should the privileges be limited on?